# Maximum independent set on non-tree representations

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, graph-theory, greedy

When attempting to derive the maximum (largest size) independent set on a graph of nodes, a solution can be arrived when the graph is a forest/tree structure. The general pseudocode for this implementation is below.

```
    S is an empty set
    While forest F has at least 1 edge
         Let v be a leaf node and let (u,v) be a lone edge incident to v
         Add v to s
    Delete both u and v from the forest, including all incident edges
    Return s + nodes remaining in forest F
```

I was wondering, if this graph is not a forest/tree (does not follow the definition) but is instead some other representation, there are obvious reasons as to why this implementation would not work, however is it possible that this algorithm could still provide an independent set within that graph, just not the maximum (largest sized) one? If so, what would that graph look like?

Comment: "Let v be a leaf node" isn't going to work if you don't have any leaves left, which can easily happen if the original graph isn't a forest.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes, for example if the graph is one big cycle. However I'm interested in looking for an input where the algorithm would terminate, but produce a non-maximum output.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica So for example if at any point before termination the algorithm has to evaluate a closed cycle, "forest" F would still have at least one edge left, so the algorithm would enter the while loop, it just would go on infinitely and not terminate.